# Removing an element from a slice duplicates the last element in Go?

Tags: go, slice

I was playing with slices in go to better understand the behaviour.
I wrote the following code:

```
func main() {
    // Initialize
    myslice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    newSlice := myslice

    fmt.Println(myslice)
    fmt.Println(newSlice)

    removeIndex := 3
    newSlice = append(newSlice[:removeIndex], newSlice[removeIndex+1:]...)
    fmt.Println(myslice)
    fmt.Println(newSlice)


}
```

This is the output:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

[1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 9]
[1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9]
```

I dont really understand what happens with **newSlice** that duplicates the 9 at the end. Also, does this mean, that this operation removes the given element from the underlying array?

https://go.dev/play/p/pf7jKw9YcfL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `append` operation simply shifts the elements of the underlying array. `newSlice` and `mySlice` are two slices with the same underlying array. The only difference is the length of the two: After `append`, `newSlice` has 8 elements, and `mySlice` still has 9 elements.

Comment: You're right, I edited the code to be consistent. Does this mean that after the append call, the underlying array will be smaller? Is there a reason the last element is repeated? I guess then if I delete more elements from newSlice, then myslice will end with 9 9 9, then 9 9 9 9, right?

Comment: No, the underlying array is still the same size. The new slice has a shorter length. That's why the original slice sees the last element as repeated.